# I'm trying to make a saving and loading system in unity but the health and fuel sliders go back to 100%

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to set up a saving/loading system in unity for a game jam I'm doing with a team, I thought I had it set up properly but when I tried to load it just went back to 100% health and jetpack fuel. Here's the code for some of the things that make it work.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public int level;
    private List<int> levels;
    public float health;
    public float fuel;
    public float[] playerpos;
    public int levelCount = SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings;



    public PlayerData(PlayerStatManager playerStats, PlayerMovement playerMovement, PlayerManager playerManager)
    {
        health = playerStats.currentHealth;
        fuel = playerMovement.currrentFuleLevel;
        playerpos = new float[] {playerManager.playerPos.x, playerManager.playerPos.y, playerManager.playerPos.z};
        levels = new List<int>();
        

        for (int i = 0; i < levelCount; i++)
        {
            levels.Add(i);
        }

        Scene activeScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        foreach (int index in levels)
        {
            if (index == activeScene.buildIndex)
            {
                level = index;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This script could be the problem, but it could also be with some of the scripts the other programmers on the team made previously, here are some other bits of code that may be the issue.

```
public static void SavePlayer(PlayerStatManager playerStats, PlayerMovement playerMovement, PlayerManager playerManager)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.sv";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(playerStats, playerMovement, playerManager);
        
        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static PlayerData LoadPlayer()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.sv";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save File not found in: " + path + "!");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

These are the main functions for saving/loading. I don't think these functions are the issue but it's better if you have more context as to what is going on in my code. It could also be the functions I pass into the PlayerData class, they are pretty large so I will try my best to give you snippets.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F2))
        {
            SaveSystem.SavePlayer(playerStatManager, this, playerManager);
        }
```

This if statement is in the Update() function and checks if the F2 key is pressed and if so does a quicksave like in the fallout games(Except fallout 76 cause multiplayer.) There's also another script that checks for a button press and if it's pressed it loads the save

```
public class LoadGame: MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerManager playerManager;
    public PlayerStatManager playerStatManager;
    public PlayerMovement playerMovement;
    
    public void when clicked()
    {
        PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();

        playerStatManager.currentHealth = data.health;
        playerMovement.currrentFuleLevel = data.fuel;
        playerManager.playerPos = new Vector3(data.playerpos[0],data.playerpos[1],data.playerpos[2]);
        
    }
}
```

If you see anything wrong with my scripts let me know(I know I should add more comments, sorry!) If you want me to add more code I can do that.

Comment: You should properly dispose the file stream, and use the `using` keyword to ensure everything is disposed properly. Also you should use `Path.Join` instead of concatenating the path manually. In addition to that, your last code snippet has a method `public void when clicked`, I believe it should be `public void WhenClicked`.
Also, how does the UI read this data? does it have direct reference to those behaviours? if so, is it updating the UI at `Start` or at `Update`?

Comment: [**STOP** using `BinaryFormatter` at all!](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [set the slider to the current values](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Image.html#UnityEngine_UI_Image_fillAmount) after you load them.